# I have problem with import from subfolders in python project

Tags: python, project-structure

hello i am working on my first python project and i have problem with importing from subfolders in project

for example this my project tree

```
C:\USERS\AHMAD\DESKTOP\myProject
│
├───project
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───core
│   │       config.py
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───libs
│   │       lib1.py
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   └───modules
│       │   __init__.py
│       │
│       ├───module1
│       |       script1.py
│       │       __init__.py
│       │
│       ├───module2
│       │       __init__.py
│       │
│       ├───module3
│       │       __init__.py
│       │
│       └───module4
│               __init__.py
```

now at **script1 in module1** how can i **import config file** from **core** folder?? is that possible ? help please!!.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/1032785

Comment: If "script1.py" is the main script where execution begins, you have to add the "project" folder to the Python path (sys.path) to do `from core import config`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher

i saw some projects on github but i didn't know how it work when import 
they use the **mainProject folder** as a **package** and import from it 
for example at script1 they can use `from project.core import config`
how can i do that with my project ??

Comment: thank you guys so much, finally i understand how it work now  :) <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered by: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

But to reiterate the point, assuming that `script1.py` is suppose to be a submodule of the package `project`, you can simply use either an absolute or relative import:

```
from project.core import config
```

or

```
from ...core import config
```

However, this DOES NOT mean you can run the script with `python script1.py`. This will not work (and will result in a `ModuleNotFoundError`). Relative and absolute imports ONLY work when the python file is being treated as a module. When you run a python file directly via `python filename`, it's being treated as the top level (main) python script and its `__name__` attribute is set to `"__main__"`. You typically shouldn't be executing module files anyways, however if you must, at dir level one above the package, run:

```
python -m project.modules.module1.script1
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a relative import to navigate backwards:

from ...core import config

Each dot before 'core' represents a parent module starting from script1.py

So, the first one is 'module1', the second one is 'modules' and the third one is the 'project'.